# How do i convert android math function to swift with logb

Tags: android, ios, swift

Hi guys i been using the formula on android app

```
valor = Math.pow(2.7183d, (((1.17896d * diametro) / 100.0d) + (0.8241d * logb(diametro / 100.0d, 2.7183d))) + 3.4987d);
```

now im implementing in Swift ios but i cant find the solution for the **logb(double,double)** the only one active on swift is **logb(double)**

```
resultado = pow(2.7183, (((2.006969 * diametro!) / 100.0) - (0.445893 * logb(diametro! / 100.0, 2.7183))) + 2.755621)
```

but i get "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

Comment: "try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" What do you think it means? You are using a too complexe calculation. Break it. Like  "let someVar = (2.006969 * diametro!) / 100.0, and then use it in the result calculation. etc.

Comment: What does `logb(double, double)` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, it appears that `logb(double, double)` is a logarithm function that returns a log to a specified `base`.  There is no equivalent for Swift, but you can write your own using the standard `log` function:

```
func logbase(_ n: Double, _ base: Double) -> Double {
    return log(n) / log(base)
}
```

That said, your original function is using `logb` to find a logarithm to base `2.7183` which is the same base that `log` uses naturally (well, to 4 decimal places) so

```
logbase(n, 2.7183)
```

and

```
log(n)
```

essentially give the same result.

Also, your formula is using `pow(2.7183, n)` to raise a base `2.7183` to a power.

But

```
pow(2.7183, n)
```

and

```
exp(n)
```

Give a similar result (only differing because `exp` uses a more accurate value for `e` - the base of natural logarithms).

Putting those together, your formula can be written as:

```
let valor = exp( ((1.17896 * diametro) / 100.0) + (0.8241 * log(diametro / 100.0)) + 3.4987 )
```

Comment: the best answer, mate you save on this, i really  appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

As Larme suggested in the comment above, just break down the equation in parts, because sometimes the compiler cannot process the complex equation due to its length.

```
original equation: 


 resultado = pow(2.7183, (((2.006969 * diametro!) / 100.0) - (0.445893 * logb(diametro! / 100.0, 2.7183))) + 2.755621)
```

Try the following way:

```
Let equation1 = 0.445893 * logb(diametro! / 100.0, 2.7183)
Let equation 2 = (2.006969 * diametro!)/100.0
Let equation 3 =  (equation2 - (equation1)) + 2.75562

resultado = pow(2.7183, equation3)
```

You can also try combinations of it or reduce the steps also.